# Is it possible to automatically separate line/scatter plot data into different series based on an additional column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

My data looks something like this:

```
H,  2015-12-11T19:44:34,    3270
W,  2015-12-11T19:44:34,    2150
H,  2015-12-11T19:49:35,    3370
W,  2015-12-11T19:49:35,    2290
...
```

As a one-off, I can get what I want by sorting the data based on the first column, making a line chart, and then manually creating two series for the H's and the W's.  Unfortunately, this data is automatically generated and is of a large but unpredictable total length, so it's tedious to do that each time I want to see a new chart.  Additionally, I may need more than two series later.  Is there a way to quickly tell the chart that I want it to automatically separate the data into different series based on the value of the first column?

There *should* be exactly one data point for each series for any one timestamp.  I say should because it's how the data is supposed to work, but I can't 100% guarantee that will always be true.

For reference, I'm using Libre Office Calc, but I'm also happy to hear answers for Microsoft Excel.

Comment: In Excel you can use a pivot chart, not sure about Calc.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, you're right.  A chart based on a pivot table is exactly what I wanted.  If you want to write up details on how to create one (in either application--it turns out they're pretty much the same steps with differently shaped UI), I'll mark the answer as correct.

Comment: To my knowledge, Calc does not support PivotCharts, so with this solution you'd need to have Excel.

Comment: LibreOffice Calc 5 supports pivot tables through the Data > Pivot Table menu, then you can make a chart from that.  If PivotChart is something other than making a chart from a pivottable, then I guess I need additional explanation.

Comment: There is a separate function for Pivot Charts in Excel, but in practice it really is just a chart based on your Pivot Table data. There are just some additional niceties to make manipulating the data (imo) a bit easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel, you can make a Pivot Chart by selecting your data and going to Insert >> Charts >> PivotChart.

Put your first column in the Axis field, second column in the Legend field, and third column in the Values field. You can change it to a line graph by selecting the chart and going to Design >> Type >> Change Chart Type.